# Why is writing SLOW on raw device, and FAST on filesystem (USB key)?

Tags: filesystems, performance, usb-drive, dd

I have a USB key ([PQI U822V-Speedy 32G](http://www.pqigroup.com/prod_in.aspx?mnuid=1286&modid=138&prodid=518)) that I am trying to benchmark quick'n'dirty on Linux. I'm testing write bandwith.

### `dd` on raw partition

I created a partition starting at sector 2048, then did a 4 GB sequential write:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M count=4096
```

I get ~22 MB/s.

I also tried several (4) `dd` running in parallel like the one above but using `count=1024` and the `seek=` option to write to different areas of the drive. Same results.

### `dd` on filesystem

However, when I format the `sdb1` partition with either `ext4` or `NTFS`, and copy big files to it (either real or `/dev/zero`), like this:

```
time dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/USBKEY/file.bin bs=1M count=4096 ; time sync
```

I do achieve > 66 MB/s as advertised by the manufacturer. Of course, I considered the `sync` duration just after the copy.

Why is there such a big performance difference?

Comment: Your file system is probably caching that - what is the difference with `o/iflag=nocache`? There are also `direct` and `sync` options which are relevant - i always use `sync` at least with usb just so i can be sure not to pull the thumbdrive too soon. And if you are `sync`ing then maybe see if you can get the same speed raw with `nonblock`

Comment: The filesystem will be writing the file somewhere other than the start of the partition.  Perhaps there is something wrong with the area near the start?  Try a single `dd` but with higher seek arguments to write to different parts of the disk.

Comment: Interesting. Could you repeat the experiment with various block-sizes (various powers of two, say 4K, 8K, 16K, 32K, 64K, 128K, 256K, 512K) but identical total data? I'm very curious if that will make a difference.

Comment: I've found Linux slow at writing to USB keys even with a FAT32 filesystem.  I've found that using `rsync --bwlimit` when copying files can actually *help*.  It seems to be something like a traffic jam: if Linux tries to ram too much data down the USB device's throat, it actually goes slower, and stays slow until I suspend the copy while the buffer flushes.  (this is with cheap USB sticks).

Answer (score 1):

Now that I look again, I realized you said this was a usb key ( flash drive ) not a hard drive.  Flash memory can only be erased in large blocks, and individual sectors can not be written without erasing them ( and the whole block they are in ) first.  Since software expects to be able to write wherever it wants on the disk at any time, the disk has translation logic in it to transparently handle the erasing.  How this is done has a dramatic affect on write performance.  Many devices use an algorithm for most of the disk that handles sequential writes very well, but sucks at random writes.  The area near the start of the disk is normally used by the FAT in the FAT filesystem they come preformatted with, and this area is randomly written to frequently, so they use a different algorithm in this area that is slower at sequential writes, but not terrible at random writes.

Thus, I am now pretty sure that my initial guess I added as a comment was right.  What you are seeing when you write to the filesystem is the performance of the rest of the disk, and when you dd at offset zero, you are writing to the fat area.  If you seek the dd destination a few hundred mb in, it should speed up considerably.

Comment: It's a bold assertion to claim any level of certainty despite no update from the asker and, 0 cited doumentation and no evidence of any of your own tests. Too bold, I think.

Comment: @mikeserv, see http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/pjd/papers/fast10-flash.pdf, and http://idke.ruc.edu.cn/people/dazhou/Papers/AsurveyFlash-JSA.pdf

Comment: Thank you. You might enjoy this: http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=3554 They did an hour long talk here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=r3GDPwIuRKI It won't let me reverse my vote. It's been too long. And you should put that in your answer - but I owe you one. No, I don't. We're even.

Comment: @psusi: so it does get better than `dd` to the raw block device and in the performed benchmark, using a file system was the enabler for this, wasn't it?

Comment: @Bananguin, no, it gets better when you write to a different part of the disk.  The fact that the filesystem happened to cause that is incidental.  Depending on what filesystem you used what else is on the disk, it very well may have decided to put the file in the "slow" part of the disk instead.

Comment: @psusi: it is deterministically incidental. that means it does get better than one contiguous write.

Comment: @Bananguin, your argument is equivalent to getting in a car accident on the way to work, and claiming that working causes car accidents.  It may be true that had you not gotten in the car at that time to go to work, you would not have been in that particular accident, but you can not conclude that working causes car accidents.  It just so happens that is where you were going when you got in one.  Here, it just so happens that the filesystem put the data in part of the disk that is faster than where the OP dd'd to.  That doesn't mean that the filesystem magically is faster than dd in general.

Answer (score 0):

Your measurement results can be explained with the kernel architecture. Using filesystem access will unlease the full potential of the kernel with all buffers and optimizations that it can do. Especially the buffers will speed up your benchmark (b/c the kernel is 100% a_A_syncronous). dd on a device file does not use any/much of this.

Comment: Writing directly to a block device *does* use the cache.

Comment: @psusi - maybe. But if there's no target file system, and `dd` is writing out sequential blocks of equal size, then which file system caches the write?

Comment: @mikeserv, the block device interface caches direct access to block devices.

Comment: @psusi so the physical device cache then or is there some in-kernel caching layer as well?

Comment: @mikeserv The block device interface is part of the kernel.

Comment: @psusi: filesystems can/do optimise accessing block devices for higher performance. no filesystem, less chance for optimisation. i am well aware of the kernel's possibilities, but i don't know how dd uses them. Actually I'd guess dd is the tool which disables everything it can disable, to ensure data arrives at the device exactly how and when dd writes it.

Comment: @Bananguin you will notice that I also use `dd` when writing to the filesystem. Also, I'm not sure that caching is *the* explanation here...

Comment: @Bananguin, the "optimization" is to avoid fragmenting files, keeping the IO contiguous.  `dd` to the raw block device is all contiguous, so that is as good as it gets.

Comment: @psusi: so the theory. Do you believe the tremendous speedup is the usb drive unleashing another couple of mbits when it senses file access? I don't, hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hdparm` instead to benchmark a drives performance with and without using any caching:

```
$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:   6314 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3157.61 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 244 MB in  3.04 seconds =  80.26 MB/sec
```

Comment: I'm benchmarking **writes**, see question title.

Comment: If I recall correctly hdparm can also do (destructive) writes.

Answer (score -2):

This happens due to the optimization of writing [Sparse files](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) in filesystem.

When you do `dd if=/dev/zero` to raw device, the zero blocks are actually written to disk.

However when you write them to a file, the filesystem ignores writing the data and saves just the metadata. This results in very few blocks being written to disk. The file can be seen as a big hole, which contains nothing.

To test performance in this manner, use **/dev/urandom** as input file ( `dd if=/dev/urandom` ). That will force filesystem to write random data into disk.

Comment: Wrong, for three reasons. **1/** I said I tested with real files: "either real or `/dev/zero`"; **2/** on many machines, `/dev/urandom` is much slower than storage devices; **3/** most often, filesystem optimisations like sparse files must be explicitly asked for, see `cp --sparse` and others...